# GAE Go "The request failed because the instance could not start successfully"

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-platform, runtime

I've been developing with Google App Engine Go for awhile, but I haven't touched it in a year. I tried updating my application from "go1" (1.9?) to "go111", and I'm currently getting some weird errors without any explanation as to what's going on.

The errors include:

- `The request failed because the instance could not start successfully`
- `Container called exit(1).`
- `500 Internal server error`
- etc.

None of these point me to any specific line in my code where something would go wrong, nor explain anything more meaningful...

I'm guessing the error is stemming from me upgrading between the golang versions. I had to change the `app` package into `main`, add a `main` function to the application, update the appengine package to a newer version, update the gsuite app, add a cloud compilation widget thingy, change app.yaml script from go to auto, etc.

All in all, I'm lost. [A Similar SE question yielded no good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48409767/cloud-endpoints-request-failed-http-status-500). [Someone else suggested `app.yaml` might be at fault, so here is mine:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53459385/handling-ah-start-route-nodejs-at-google-app-engine)

```
runtime:     go111

handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static
- url: /res
  static_dir: res
- url: /update
  script: auto
  secure: always
  login: admin
- url: /.*
  script: auto
  secure: always
  login: optional
```

Debug console log is very unhelpful:

[image]

And the main file looks essentially like:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "google.golang.org/appengine"
    "html/template"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

var MainTemplate *template.Template

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", hello)

    var err error
    MainTemplate, err = template.ParseFiles("html/main.html")
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("ERROR! %v\n", err.Error())
        panic(err)
    }
    log.Printf("Hello world!\n")
}


func hello(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    c := appengine.NewContext(r)
    //................................//
    MainTemplate.Execute(w, nil)
}
```

Anything else it could be?

Comment: Most likely your code crashed. Add the error messages from Stackdriver plus your code.

Comment: @JohnHanley Added the log, plus the basic code. Main function doesn't appear to crash, no errors pointing to anything going wrong...

Comment: @ThePiachu you appear to be missing a call to http.ListenAndServe.  Take a look at the helloworld.go example in the [go111 getting started page](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go111/building-app/).  Without that, your app is going to exit without ever listening for any requests (alternatively, it appears you can call appengine.Main per the [migration guide](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go111/go-differences#package-main)).

Comment: The code that you posted could not have worked before in App Engine. Your code starts, processes templates, and exits. No web server process is started.

Comment: @JohnHanley yeah, that function used to be `init()`, but then appengine nagged me about not having a `main` package and a `main()` function, so I just switched init to main. I guess my mind glossed over the ListenAndServe from the example, since it was nested inside of a log... https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/golang-samples/blob/master/appengine/go11x/helloworld/helloworld.go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, after some help from a few comments, here are a few issues that I had to fix to get my code to work:

1. I converted my `init()` function into `main()` without adding a way to listen to requests. The code just ran through the `main()` function and exited without an error, hence the problems with debugging.
2. `appengine.NewContext(r)` is deprecated apparently, so I had to switch those statements to `r.Context()`. MEANWHILE, `Appengine Datastore` is still using `golang.org/x/net/context` and not just `context`, so if you want to use things like `RunInTransaction()`, DON'T update your imports, `context` casts into `golang.org/x/net/context` just fine
3. If you [follow the official examples](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/golang-samples/blob/master/appengine/go11x/helloworld/helloworld.go) provided by Google, you will most likely run into errors like `textPayload: "2019/10/20 22:32:46 http: panic serving 127.0.0.1:16051: not an App Engine context`. Instead, your code needs to look like the below example.
4. Since the former `app` package is now the `main` package, make sure that any files that are referenced in `app.yaml` (`favicon.ico` for example) are in a proper position in relation to the `main` package (I had to move mine to a different folder to avoid errors popping up every request...).

```
package main

import (
    "google.golang.org/appengine"
    "html/template"
    "net/http"
)

var MainTemplate *template.Template

func init() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", hello)
    MainTemplate, _= template.ParseFiles("html/main.html")
}

func main() {
    appengine.Main()
}

func hello(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    c := r.Context()
    //................................//
    MainTemplate.Execute(w, nil)
}
```

This ought to work. `appengine.Main()` apparently connects you to all the `appengine` functionality needed to use the context for datastore / memcache / whatever operations.

Thank you to the commenters that helped me get over the first hump!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is missing the part to start a listener. Add this to your code:

```
    port := os.Getenv("PORT")
    if port == "" {
            port = "8080"
            log.Printf("Defaulting to port %s", port)
    }
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(fmt.Sprintf(":%s", port), nil))
```

Comment: Close, but that apparently doesn't let you use the `Context` properly for `datastore` and what have you. So it's good enough to display a web page, but not good enough for a full appengine app...

Comment: @ThePiachu - Where is Datastore in your question?

Comment: It wasn't, I use it a few layers deeper, didn't know it was an issue until the first layer of issues was fixed.